# How to connect to node port from angular 2 project

Tags: node.js, express

js file in folder A which handles my routes and connect to database and it looks like this

```
var express = require('express');        // call express
var app = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/ExpenseUsers");

var User = require('./Models/Users');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 5555;        // set our port

var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the      express Router

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
next();
});

router.route('')
.post(function (req, response) {

    var user = new User(req.body);

    user.save(function (err, resource) {
        if (err) {
            response.send(err).status(501);
        } else {
            response.json(resource).status(201);
        }
    });

})

.get(function (req, res) {
    User.find(function (err, users) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(users);
    });
})


router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to my api!' });
});

app.use('/User', router);

app.listen(port);
```

I tried creating user using Postman tool and it worked fine.Then i cloned a angular2 project in some other folder when i run the angular2 it opened on port 5555.Then i got this error in server.js saying

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5555
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here.

Comment: it means the port 5555 is already in use, try different port

Comment: I changed the port number in server.js to 5556 ... I made a http call in angular like this     
`CreateUser(UserInfo: any) {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post("/User", JSON.stringify(UserInfo), { headers: headers }).map(response => response.json());
    }`
Then i get this error `POST http://localhost:5555/User 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0):

It's very clear error message and it says port 5555 is used by another process.

You must change Angular's or web server's port (I recommend changing Angular's port because if you change web server's port you must change its' references on Angular code as well).